# TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple for project router planner project

Tags: python

This is the function I want to excuate, I want to show the graph in jupyter notebook.

```py
def show_map(M, start=None, goal=None, path=None):
    G = M._graph
    pos = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos')
    edge_trace = Scatter(
        x=[],
        y=[],
        line=Line(width=0.5, color='#888'),
        hoverinfo='none',
        mode='lines')

    for edge in G.edges():
        x0, y0 = G.node[edge[0]]['pos']
        x1, y1 = G.node[edge[1]]['pos']
        edge_trace['x'] += [x0, x1, None]
        edge_trace['y'] += [y0, y1, None]
```

this is the error i get

```py
    109         x0, y0 = G.node[edge[0]]['pos']
    110         x1, y1 = G.node[edge[1]]['pos']
--> 111         edge_trace['x'] += [x0, x1, None]
    112         edge_trace['y'] += [y0, y1, None]
    113 

TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple
```

I don't understand why it is a tuple?

The attributes are:

```
map_10_dict = {
    0: {'pos': [0.7798606835438107, 0.6922727646627362], 'connections': [7, 6, 5]},
    1: {'pos': [0.7647837074641568, 0.3252670836724646], 'connections': [4, 3, 2]},
    2: {'pos': [0.7155217893995438, 0.20026498027300055], 'connections': [4, 3, 1]},
    3: {'pos': [0.7076566826610747, 0.3278339270610988], 'connections': [5, 4, 1, 2]},
    4: {'pos': [0.8325506249953353, 0.02310946309985762], 'connections': [1, 2, 3]},
    5: {'pos': [0.49016747075266875, 0.5464878695400415], 'connections': [7, 0, 3]},
    6: {'pos': [0.8820353070895344, 0.6791919587749445], 'connections': [0]},
    7: {'pos': [0.46247219371675075, 0.6258061621642713], 'connections': [0, 5]},
    8: {'pos': [0.11622158839385677, 0.11236327488812581], 'connections': [9]},
    9: {'pos': [0.1285377678230034, 0.3285840695698353], 'connections': [8]}
}
```

Comment: What is the result of ```print(type(edge_trace['x']))```?

Comment: <class 'tuple'>

Comment: Well, that is your answer. ```edge_trace['x'] += [x0, x1, None]``` is concatenating a tuple and a list. To know why edge_trace['x'] is a tuple, I think you'd need to consult the ```Scatter``` function signature.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I will look up document see if I can figure out